# Dropbox API and PHP

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I am gelling following error while trying to read file content which is residing in a subfolder rather than a parent folder.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid
>   signature. Expected signature base string:
>   GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi-content.dropbox.com%2F1%2Ffiles%2Fdropbox%2FProjects%2FMAC%2520Error.rtf&oauth_consumer_key%3Dbdagb07uu6zq827%26oauth_nonce%3D46d063d5815a0972d63cf72359c0349f%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1324449973%26oauth_token%3D7f2cr9kppqo2hxz%26oauth_version%3D1.0
>   (Status Code: 403)' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dbcatalog/BenTheDesigner-Dropbox-88e3876/Dropbox/OAuth/Consumer/Curl.php:133
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dbcatalog/BenTheDesigner-Dropbox-88e3876/Dropbox/API.php(109):
>   Dropbox\OAuth\Consumer\Curl->fetch('GET', 'https://api-con...',
>   'files/dropbox/P...', Array) #1
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dbcatalog/BenTheDesigner-Dropbox-88e3876/check.php(21):
>   Dropbox\API->getFile('Projects/MAC Er...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dbcatalog/BenTheDesigner-Dropbox-88e3876/Dropbox/OAuth/Consumer/Curl.php
>   on line 133

I am using Ben's Dropbox Library for php

https://github.com/BenTheDesigner/Dropbox

Thanks

Comment: I assume you filled in `$key` and `$secret` correctly... not familiar with the Dropbox API, but I'm guessing you need to sign up for an API key.

Comment: Have you tried searching their forums? http://forums.dropbox.com/tags.php?tag=invalid-signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a simple PHP-API you can find one here:

https://github.com/hawaiianchimp/Dropbox-PHP-API/

Answer (score 0):

This is the message thats returned when a OAuth request is signed incorrectly.  This is likely the fault of the library you're using.  At first glance, it looks like it may be encoding the name of your "MAC Error.rtf" file incorrectly.   Checkout the PHP SDK dropbox mentions on its website as an alternative and raise this issue with the library's owner.

The code that generates this would help too.